# Is there a better way to accept full name of user in structures from the console in C language?

Tags: c, struct, switch-statement, fgets

This is a mini project for library management system. The problem is that first fgets function for user input in case 1 falls through no matter the content but that of the subsequent ones works. I want to accept the full name of the book name and the author which contains whitespaces from the console.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Structure definition
struct library
{
    char bookName[50];
    char authorName[50];
    int numberOfPages;
    float price;

};

int main()
{
    // Structure Variable declaration
    struct library lib[50];
    // Variables initialization
    int i,j,keepcount;
    i=j=keepcount = 0;
    // Character arrays
    char arth_nm[50],book_nm[50];


    while(j!=7)
    {
        // Menu Selection
        printf("\n\n1. Add book information\n2. Display book information\n");
        printf("3. List all books of given author\n");
        printf("4. List the title of specified book\n");
        printf("5. List the count of books in the library\n");
        printf("6. Display Highest Price Book\n");
        printf("7. Exit");
        printf ("\n\nSelect one of the above: \n");
        scanf("%d",&j);


        switch(j)
        {
        // Entering book details
         case 1:
            printf ("Enter book name:  ");
            fgets(lib[i].bookName, sizeof(lib[i].bookName), stdin);

            printf ("Enter author name: ");
            fgets(lib[i].authorName, sizeof(lib[i].authorName), stdin);

            printf ("Enter pages: ");
            scanf ("%d",&lib[i].numberOfPages);

            printf ("Enter price: ");
            scanf ("%f",&lib[i].price);

            keepcount++;
        break;

       // All book details entered
        case 2:
            printf("You have entered the following information\n");
            for(i=0; i<keepcount; i++)
            {
                printf ("Book name = %s",lib[i].bookName);

                printf ("\tAuthor name = %s",lib[i].authorName);

                printf ("\tPages = %d",lib[i].numberOfPages);

                printf ("\tPrice = %f",lib[i].price);

                printf("\n");
            }

        break;

        // Searching for book details by using the name of the Author
        case 3:
        printf ("Enter author name : ");
        scanf ("%s",arth_nm);
        for (i=0; i<keepcount; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(arth_nm, lib[i].authorName) == 0)
            printf ("%s %s %d %f",lib[i].bookName,lib[i].authorName,lib[i].numberOfPages,lib[i].price);
        }
        break;

        // Searching for book details by using the name of the book
        case 4:
        printf ("Enter book name : ");
        scanf ("%s",book_nm);
        for (i=0; i<keepcount; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(book_nm, lib[i].bookName) == 0)
            printf ("%s \t %s \t %d \t %f",lib[i].bookName,lib[i].authorName,lib[i].numberOfPages,lib[i].price);
        }
        break;
        // Case for Total many of books shelved
        case 5:
        printf("\n No of books in library : %d", keepcount);
        break;

        // Case for Highest paid book
        case 6:
        printf ("Highest Price Book : ");
        float temp = 0;
        for (i=0;i<keepcount;i++)
        {
            if(temp < lib[i].price)
                temp = lib[i].price;
        }
        printf("%f", temp);

        break;

        case 7:
        exit (0);


    }


    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It "falls through" because of the newline you entered (but not read) in the `scanf("%d",&j);` call you used to read the menu selection. I suggest you use `fgets` for that too, and use `sscanf` to get the menu selection.

Comment: Don't mix `fgets()` with `scanf()`.  Better to use `fgets()` only.  Also `fgets()` is saving the `'\n'` in the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `fgets()` statement for accepting whitespaces:

```
fgets(arth_nm, 50, stdin);
```

You should `fflush(stdout)` it to clear the output buffer like this:

```
fflush(stdout);
fgets(arth_nm, 50, stdin);
```

It'll help you to fix this.

Comment: Passing an input-only stream (like `stdin`) to `fflush` is explicitly mentioned in the C specification as *undefined behavior*. Some systems add it as a non-portable extension, but it can't be counted on to work everywhere. To "flush" standard input in a portable way, read character by character until you get either `EOF` or a newline. And remember that all character-reading functions returns an *`int`*, which is important for the `EOF` check.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm very well aware of the undefined behavior by `fflush()`, but it seems like it's the best solution for not letting the program skip for input

Answer (score 0):

yes , there is, as @Rohan Bari said, you can use `fgets()` , though some compilers does not supports the use of this function. Alternatively, you can use
 `scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", variableName);`
this function takes the input till a new line or enter is pressed, i.e, it will read any character including whitesapces.i hope i've been able to help.